# SQL: Nested Select vs Double JOIN by Performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, join, select

I have report based on a stored procedures and I need to add User name into output.

In my system TWO users can be owners of transaction.

Also, in my system User information stored in different database.

So, I see only two ways to add User name:

**CASE 1**

```
SELECT 
    E.*,
    CASE WHEN (E.UserDetailsId IS NULL AND E.UserDetailsId2 IS NULL)
            THEN 'N/A'
        ELSE
        (SELECT CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', LastName) AS UserName 
            FROM UserDb.dbo.UserDetails WHERE (
            (UserDetailsId IS NOT NULL AND UserDetailsId = E.UserDetailsId)
            OR 
            (UserDetailsId2 IS NOT NULL AND UserDetailsId2 = E.UserDetailsId)
            )
    END AS UserName,
FROM 
    TransactionDetail E
WHERE 
    E.TransactionDetailTypeId = @TypeId
```

**CASE 2**

```
SELECT 
    E.*,
    CASE WHEN (E.UserDetailsId IS NULL AND E.UserDetailsId2 IS NULL)
            THEN 'N/A'
        ELSE
    CASE WHEN (E.UserDetailsId IS NOT NULL)
        THEN CONCAT(UD.FirstName, ' ', UD.LastName)
    CASE WHEN (E.UserDetailsId2 IS NOT NULL)
        THEN CONCAT(UD2.FirstName, ' ', UD2.LastName)
    END AS UserName
FROM 
    TransactionDetail E
    JOIN UserDb.dbo.UserDetails UD ON UD.UserDetailsId = E.UserDetailsId
    JOIN UserDb.dbo.UserDetails UD2 ON UD2.UserDetailsId = E.UserDetailsId
WHERE 
    E.TransactionDetailTypeId = @TypeId
```

I've tried to do performance test on my local machine with 1 million of test transactions and 10 thousand of users, but results were equal.

What is the best way to do it from performance point of view and **why**?

The real database contains about 20 million transactions divided by 10 groups and 100 thousand of users.

Comment: Learn to review your own code. Your second query is not correct. You joined to UserDetails twice using the same value - using a magically populated variable. Next, you need to account for no matching rows in both joins as you did in the first query. No sense in comparing performance until the queries are logically the same. And since you did not find this error, one must also suspect your test data is not representative of all possibilities. Perhaps it also is not statistically representative of live data as well. Also only displaying a single user name - which seems a problem.

Comment: @GeorgM . . . Your queries are not the same.  The first references one parameter.  The second references three.  You should use the one that accurately implements the logic you want.

Comment: @SMor, Gordon Linoff  Thank you for comments, It was helpful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try with this following script? This should return the same result your query is returning.

> Please test the output is same as your query or not. If mismatch, just ignore this solution.

```
SELECT E.*,
CASE 
    WHEN (E.UserDetailsId IS NULL AND E.UserDetailsId2 IS NULL) THEN 'N/A'
    ELSE  CONCAT(FirstName, '  ', LastName) 
END AS UserName 
FROM TransactionDetail E
LEFT JOIN UserDetails UD  
    ON (E.UserDetailsId = UD.UserDetailsId) 
    OR (E.UserDetailsId2 = UD.UserDetailsId)
WHERE E.TransactionDetailTypeId = @TypeId
```

Answer (score 0):

From a performance perspective and your description, I would expect the following to have the best performance:

```
SELECT E.*,
       (CASE WHEN E.UserDetailsId IS NOT NULL
             THEN CONCAT(UD.FirstName, ' ', UD.LastName)
             WHEN E.UserDetailsId2 IS NOT NULL
             THEN CONCAT(UD2.FirstName, ' ', UD2.LastName),
             ELSE 'N/A'
        END) AS UserName
FROM TransactionDetail E LEFT JOIN
     UserDb.dbo.UserDetails UD
     ON UD.UserDetailsId = E.UserDetailsId LEFT JOIN
     UserDb.dbo.UserDetails UD2
     ON UD2.UserDetailsId = E.UserDetailsId2
WHERE E.TransactionDetailTypeId = @TypeId;
```

You then want indexes on `TransactionDetail(TransactionDetailTypeId)` and `UserDetails(UserDetailsId)`.

The use of `OR` in the `ON` condition could have two bad effects.  The first is performance.  `OR` can be bad for performance.  This is mitigated for this example because you are presumably matching only one row because of the `WHERE` clause.

The second is that you will get two rows if both fields are populated -- and you seem to only want one row for the transaction id.

Comment: It's cool solution, Thanks a lot! And finnaly, I found my issue

Comment: @GeorgM . . . You find that the solution with `or` performs better than this?

Answer (score 0):

Another option to try:

```
( SELECT ... 'N/A' ...
    FROM TransactionDetail E 
    WHERE  E.TransactionDetailTypeId = @TypeId
       AND E.UserDetailsId  IS  NULL
       AND E.UserDetailsId2 IS  NULL )
UNION ALL
( SELECT ... UD... ...
    FROM TransactionDetail E JOIN UserDetails UD
    WHERE  E.TransactionDetailTypeId = @TypeId
       AND E.UserDetailsId  IS NOT NULL
       AND E.UserDetailsId2 IS  NULL )
UNION ALL
( SELECT ... UD2... ...
    FROM TransactionDetail E JOIN UserDetails UD2
    WHERE  E.TransactionDetailTypeId = @TypeId
       AND E.UserDetailsId  IS  NULL
       AND E.UserDetailsId2 IS NOT NULL )
UNION ALL
( SELECT ... UD...UD2... ...
    FROM TransactionDetail E JOIN UserDetails UD JOIN UserDetails UD2
    WHERE  E.TransactionDetailTypeId = @TypeId
       AND E.UserDetailsId  IS NOT NULL
       AND E.UserDetailsId2 IS NOT NULL) )
```

It *may* help to have `INDEX(TransactionDetailTypeId, UserDetailsId, UserDetailsId2)`